# .NET - define a new control instance's properties in short way?

Tags: c#

In general, if we have to create new control instance, we will do the following:

```
Literal ltl= new Literal(); 
ltl.ID = "ltlControl1";
ltl.Text = "SomeText";
PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ltl);
```

But is it possible define the properties like that to shorten the syntax?

```
Literal ltl= new Literal( ID = "ltlControl1", Text = "SomeText");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following with [C# object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

```
var ltl = new Literal {
    ID = "ltlControl1",
    Text = "SomeText"
};

Placeholder.Controls.Add(ltl);
```

Or even shorter if you don't need the `ltl` variable.

```
Placeholder.Controls.Add(new Literal {ID="ltlControl1", Text="SomeText"});
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by using the object initializer syntax. You're close; substitute the parentheses with curly braces to assign the properties.

```
Literal ltl = new Literal { ID = "ltlControl1", Text = "SomeText" };
```

For more information refer to [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).